# How do I get an event in Log Analytics with different parameterxml values?

Tags: azure, service, monitoring

First, I hope that you understood my question correctly. 
In Log Analytics I have an query just like this:

```
Event
| where EventID == 7036 and Computer == "testSQLServer"
and ParameterXml == "<Param>SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER)</Param><Param>stopped</Param><Param>-</Param>"
```

This query works and now I want to get results that fits "EventID" and "Computer" AND one of a pool of "ParameterXml" entries.

To be specific, this pool contains 5 "ParameterXml" lines:

```
ParameterXml == "<Param>SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER)</Param><Param>stopped</Param><Param>-</Param>" 
ParameterXml == "<Param>SQL Server Agent (MSSQLSERVER)</Param><Param>stopped</Param><Param>-</Param>"
ParameterXml == "<Param>SQL Server Integration Services 13.0</Param><Param>stopped</Param><Param>-</Param>"
ParameterXml == "<Param>SQL Server Analysis Services (MULTIDIM)</Param><Param>stopped</Param><Param>-</Param>"
```

So how do I get results with "EventID" and "Computer" AND one of these "ParameterXml"? I don't want to get results if all "ParameterXml" fit or other "ParameterXml" (from other Services) fit to the search.

I tried with different ways of "AND" and "OR" but I don't get it.

Do you have an idea? Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more elegant way is to use the operator `"in"` instead of `"or"`, like below:

```
Event
| where EventID == 7036 and Computer == "testSQLServer"
| where ParameterXml in ("<Param>SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER)</Param><Param>stopped</Param><Param>-</Param>", 
                         "<Param>SQL Server Agent (MSSQLSERVER)</Param><Param>stopped</Param><Param>-</Param>", 
                         "<Param>SQL Server Integration Services 13.0</Param><Param>stopped</Param><Param>-</Param>",
                         "<Param>SQL Server Analysis Services (MSSQLSERVER)</Param><Param>stopped</Param><Param>-</Param>")
```

Comment: Thank you! Indeed that looks pretty more elegant

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I asked a friend for help. I had to add a further "where" operator, so the correct query is:

```
Event
| where EventID == 7036 and Computer == "testSQLServer"
| where ParameterXml == "<Param>SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER)</Param><Param>stopped</Param><Param>-</Param>" 
or ParameterXml == "<Param>SQL Server Agent (MSSQLSERVER)</Param><Param>stopped</Param><Param>-</Param>" 
or ParameterXml == "<Param>SQL Server Integration Services 13.0</Param><Param>stopped</Param><Param>-</Param>" 
or ParameterXml == "<Param>SQL Server Analysis Services (MSSQLSERVER)</Param><Param>stopped</Param><Param>-</Param>"
```

Happy monitoring!